# How to get rid of delay between clicking on button and execution of animation?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I'm creating a hamburger menu. I have animations for menu to appear and hide after clicking on button. When I click on button to display  the menu everything is fine but when i click on it to hide it there is a delay (and delay is equal to animation time). I've tried everything to get rid of this delay, but nothing works.

```
@keyframes appear {
    from {
        max-height: 0;
    }
    to {
        max-height: 100vh;
    }
}
@keyframes hide {
    from {
        max-height: 100vh;
    }
    to {
        max-height: 0;
    }
}

.header__menu{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 2.6em;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100vw;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    @include concert-one;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    background-color: $violet;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
}
```

and JS

```
hamburgerMenu.style.display = "none";

hamburgerButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (hamburgerMenu.style.display == "none") {
        hamburgerMenu.style.animation = "appear 1s ease-in both";
        hamburgerMenu.style.display = "flex"
    } else if (hamburgerMenu.style.display == "flex") {
        hamburgerMenu.style.animation = "hide 1s ease-in both";
        setTimeout(() => {
            hamburgerMenu.style.display = "none";
        }, 1000);
    } 
})
```

HTML

```
    <header class="header">
        <div class="header__logo">
            travel
        </div>
        <nav class="header__nav">
            <a href="#"><img src="public/img/icons/whatsapp.svg" alt="Whatsapp"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="public/img/icons/twitter.svg" alt="Twitter"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="public/img/icons/facebook.svg" alt="Facebook"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="public/img/icons/instagram.svg" alt="instagram"></a>
        </nav>
        <div class="header__hamburger">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="header__menu">
            <span>Whatsapp</span>
            <span>Twitter</span>
            <span>Facebook</span>
            <span>Instagram</span>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: The animation won’t be seen to be doing anything to start with because it’s taking the max height down from 100vh so unless your hamburger menu is that high  we won’t see anything until near the  end.

Comment: Could you show the HTML for the element?

Comment: Oh,yeah that makes sense. I've tried to change max height  to smaller number  but now there is another problem. Small delay is still here if this number larger than actual height of menu but I also can't set exactly same number as a height of the menu because it differs on different screen sizes. I added html to my question. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, anything other than the exact height will cause a delay.

Comment: Am I right in assuming that the hamburger is drawn with those three spans? How are their dimensions and positioning decided?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've used rem units 
    span{
        display: block;
        width: 2.3rem;
        height: .25rem;
        background-color: $violet;
        border-radius: 2px;
        margin-bottom:  .5rem;
        &:last-child{
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }
    }

Comment: How about putting these bits of code together to make a snippet that is runnable? It makes it very much easier to give a relevant answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have your setTimeout set for 1sec. you can reduce that to a fraction of a second. this should work.

Try this:

```
hamburgerMenu.style.display = "none";

hamburgerButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (hamburgerMenu.style.display == "none") {
        hamburgerMenu.style.animation = "appear 1s ease-in both";
        hamburgerMenu.style.display = "flex"
    } else if (hamburgerMenu.style.display == "flex") {
        hamburgerMenu.style.animation = "hide 1s ease-in both";
        setTimeout(() => {
            hamburgerMenu.style.display = "none";
        }, 100);
    } 
})
```

Comment: I've tried,but then display: none is set earlier than animation property. That was the reason why i set that timeout